# Will HR agree to extend my joining date by one week

Tags: notice-period

I had an HR round where I was asked to join in a month.

I discussed with my current manager and he agreed for a date which is one week more than the joining date expected.

Can the new company HR postpone my joining for one week only?

Comment: ... have you asked them?

Comment: Which did you agree to first?  If you agreed to a start date and now your current employer wants you to stay for longer.  I don't see why you'd agree to a leave date that's greater than your new start date.  You've already chosen to leave the company.  Your former employer risks nothing by making you postpone your start date and may even be using this as a tactic to keep you there.  You risk the new job even asking for an extension on a date you've already agreed to.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to ask them, plain and simple. Don't sugar coat things, don't try to butter them up; explain your situation thoroughly, and hope that they will accommodate. Typically, a week isn't an awful thing to ask for, especially if you give them plenty of notice. Each company is different though, as well as each HR department.

Answer (score 1):

This question/answer is completely and totally dependent on not only the region, but the company you are talking about. A smaller company, companies that are generally more laid-back fashion may allow the week, however, a large corporation may not.

The only way you will get an answer is to speak with them, and let them know what you spoke to your current manager about. If they have questions or concerns, they will likely politely let you know, and then discuss them with your current manager.

If your current manager has any weight, they may be able to help you out should the HR staff have an issue with the week.

Comment: Though, quite often, companies ASK when you can start, not demand, so if you give a heads up and tell them you need one more week, I'd be surprised if even a large corporation would pass on a candidate good enough to hire over that.  One way to find out, I guess.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet This is true, I've never really heard of a company demanding a start date, and I certainly would not want to work for a company that had an issue with one week extra.

Comment: @JakenHerman, sometimes there are contractual reasons for a start date, they may need to have a person in place by a set date to fulfil their contract with a client, so don't reject places just because they can't accommodate every time.